# How to duplicate all rows in SQL Database table and change data in one of the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have an SQL DATABASE and I want to duplicate all rows from a table named "searches", that have the word "google" in the column named "search_url". The records in this table are more than 300,000 so I don't want to duplicate them all, just the ones that have "google" in the column named "search_url".

The new rows' ID should automatically increment, and all the rest of the columns must be the same, except for the column named "search_url" where "google" has to become "search.yahoo"

My SQL is not that good and I will appreciate all the help I can get! Thank you :)

EDIT:

Sample data:

```
ID SEARCH_URL                                SEARCHABLE_ID SEARCHABLE_TYPE
1  https://www.google.com/search?q=camping   1             App\News
2  https://www.google.com/search?q=hiking    2             App\News
```

So I want this to become after this is duplicate:

```
ID SEARCH_URL                                SEARCHABLE_ID SEARCHABLE_TYPE
1  https://www.google.com/search?q=camping   1             App\News
2  https://www.google.com/search?q=hiking    2             App\News
3  https://search.yahoo.com/?q=camping       1             App\News
4  https://search.yahoo.com/?q=hiking        2             App\News
```

Comment: Look at: [`INSERT .. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). Read the link. Try it and edit your question with the attempt you have made.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab: Please share your structure of searches with some sample data and expected output .

Comment: The title and question are contradictory

Comment: @Suresh I added the sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Strawberry I wasn't sure how to ask the question. The title was indeed a problem for me.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab: Your question should be explained in a well mannered with proper input and output. If there is an error in your problem then it should posted as it is. :) Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a step by step. Follow this process so you don't end up inserting a load of bad data.

1) Select the rows you want, except the autoincrement primary key id - mysql will manage that itself:

```
SELECT SEARCH_URL, SEARCHABLE_ID, SEARCHABLE_TYPE FROM TABLE --where .. ?
```

Use a where clause if you don't want all rows

2) You modify the data according to your wish. Here we use the string replace function to change google into yahoo:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SEARCH_URL, 'google', 'search.yahoo'), SEARCHABLE_ID, SEARCHABLE_TYPE FROM TABLE
```

Check it looks good.. *(You said you wanted to change **google -> search.yahoo** but strictly speaking your example data demands **www.google -> search.yahoo**)* - CHECK YOUR DATA BEFORE YOU INSERT IT

3) Then add in an insert above it, to insert into your table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(SEARCH_URL, SEARCHABLE_ID, SEARCHABLE_TYPE)
SELECT REPLACE(SEARCH_URL, 'google', 'search.yahoo'), SEARCHABLE_ID, SEARCHABLE_TYPE FROM TABLE
```

You need to specify the full set of columns you're inserting, and you have to specify the same count of columns for insert as you have selected.

If you have an autoincrementing primary key, you can't do an `insert into table select * from table` because that will select the ID column and then try to insert what will technically be a bunch of already-existing values

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to get the desired output:

```
INSERT INTO searches(search_url, searchable_id,searchable_type)
SELECT REPLACE(search_url, 'google', 'search.yahoo'), searchable_id,searchable_type FROM searches;
```

Hope it works for you.